# Embedding PDF in browser from Django Model file

Tags: html, pdf, django-templates, wagtail

I'm having trouble displaying a PDF in a django template. When I use this code it fails.

```
<object data="{{ MyObject.file.url}}" type="application/pdf">                                                                                                        
   <embed src="{{ MyObject.file.url}}" type='application/pdf'>                                                                                                   
</object>
```

It displays a page broken and when i look at the browser console I get.

```
refused to display 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'."
```

So I changed the settings in my Django settings file to include "X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'" it still doesn't work.

I suspect it something to do with Django configuration because when I swap data/src to "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" a publicly hosted PDF it display s no problem.